# Best way to insert unique random ID in MySQL/PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, random

I've seen many ways to do this but I'd like to know which one would be the best. I'm working on a school project, so the security isn't **that** important but the ID should also be impossible to just quess.

I tried using UUID_SHORT() in MySQL but the number it returns are not really random (9863897830706381**6**, 9863897830706381**7**...)

Comment: perhaps the id could be composed of two parts (so two columns) - comprising an incrementing integer, and a random string?

Comment: UUIDs are generally not random, generally don't need to be, and even if you were using the long-form UUID function mySQL still doesn't use the random algo.

Comment: Normally, visibility wouldn't be implemented at this level. Can you give us some more information about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: 'id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT' Id field functionality is built into mysql.  It automatically handles many conditions you are probably not aware of.

Comment: You state "using MySQL/PHP", have you tried letting php do the generation?

Comment: @El_Vanja Haven't tried PHP yet. Maybe I could just get a number fron random_int() and then check if it already exists in the database?

Comment: That's a viable approach for the scope of a school project. If you give the method a large enough range, you'll minimize the chance of duplication, but you should still make the check.